# Internal CSS injected by JavaScript is not applying

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm adding a `div` into my webpage using JavaScript and along with that `div` I'm adding a bit of CSS code so the code looks like this

```
   <script>
var rand= randomString();
    var html = '<div class="'+rand+'">Welcome to StackOverflow!</div>
    <style>.'+rand+'{color:red}</style>';

    document.getElementById("parent_div").innerHTML = html;

function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 18;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    return  randomstring;
}
    </script>
```

This is working most of the time, and for some reason this CSS is not applying to this `div`, but CSS is injected along with the HTML. I also changed the order, added CSS first and then HTML but no luck, failing only few times despite same code working most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

CSS will not be applied if it is not in the `head` unless it is using the `scoped` attribute and the `style` tag is inside the element it will be applied to.

This should work for you:

```
<script>
var html = '<div class="rule"><style scoped>.rule{color:red}</style>Welcome to StackOverflow!</div>';

document.getElementById("parent_div").innerHTML = html;
</script>
```

If you want more info on how this works, here's a good article for you: http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding stylesheets like that, try this:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.rule','color: red;');
var html = '<div class="rule">Welcome to StackOverflow!</div>';
document.getElementById("parent_div").innerHTML(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("parent_div").innerHTML = html
```

You need to set css this way.

Check this  https://jsfiddle.net/3xs1bsrp/1/

Comment: You have one space between `</div><style>.rule{color:red}` just remove that and then use `.innerHTML = html`

Comment: that was not the reason, class name was the problem-solved BTW

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug in my program, I was using a random string generator for `class` and when the random string first character was number it failed when it started with a character it worked

```
.3as324sdfsr4 => faield

.wer6sdf74hjg => worked
```

so I added a character in front of return string to solve this

```
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 18;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    return  's'+randomstring;
}
```